# Can I play with my friends on Xbox One without Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

I will am getting an Xbox One for Christmas and was wondering if I needed Xbox Live to play with my brother, his friends, and my friends.

Comment: Yes, you need xbox live

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you simply mean a registered account or do you mean a paid subscription?

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your definition of "play with".

**To play online with anyone, you will need an xbox live account.**

To play "locally" (meaning everyone is in the same room taking turns or playing on the same tv via a splitscreen mode, but not all games support that) I do not believe you need an xbox live account.